# How do I keep the 0's in a Date

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how it is that I can keep the 0's or add them when I grab a date.

What Im getting is this:

6/15/2010

What I'm tring to get is:

06/15/2010

I have added it so that it checks the length to and if its less than 6 (im stripping the "/") it pads the left side. That solves the issue when the month is a single digit, but what about when the date is a single digit.

My ultimate goal is to have a date such as:

1/1/2010

read out like:

01/01/2010

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a custom format : dd/MM/yyyy, or in your case MM/dd/yyyy. Note the capital M, the small m gets you the minutes.

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [custom DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
string str = someDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of date you are using.

For instance, `dd/MM/yyyy` will produce `01/05/2009` and `d/M/yyyy` would produce `1/5/2009`

A complete reference can be found there : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
string myDate = "1/1/2010";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(myDate);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

If the starting date is some other unrecognized format you could use `DateTime.ParseExact();`

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.ParseExact() to parse the string into a valid datetime object and then use DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")  to get result in desired format.